# Not able to Switch Fragments on clicking Navigation items?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am not able to Switch fragments on clicking the Navigation Items.I am not using menu items to populate in the Navigation Drawer.

activity_dashboard layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
            <include
                layout="@layout/app_bar_dashboard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#23282e"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
                    android:background="@mipmap/login"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/avatar"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/nav_user_pic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Sunil Nepali"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Student"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#008b8b"
                        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="11dp"
                        android:text="INSTITUTION"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dashboard_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="#2e353d"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/dashboard" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="Dashboard"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#23282e" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/calender_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="#2e353d"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/calander" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="Calendar"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#23282e" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/view_fee"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="#2e353d"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/fee" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="Fee"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#008b8b"
                        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="11dp"
                        android:text="ACADEMICS"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/class_schedule"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="#2e353d"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/class_schedule" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="Class Schedule"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#23282e" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/progress_report"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="#2e353d"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/progess_report" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="Progress Report"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#008b8b"
                        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="11dp"
                        android:text="ACCOUNT"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/view_profile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="#2e353d"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/view_profile" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="View Profile"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#23282e" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="#2e353d"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/settings" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="Settings"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#23282e" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="#2e353d"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/logout" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="Log Out"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Home Class

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        LinearLayout dashboard, calendar, classSchedule, progressReport, profile, fee;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            calendar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.calender_layout);
            classSchedule = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.class_schedule);
            profile = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_profile);
            fee = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_fee);
            progressReport = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_report);
            //    calendar.setOnClickListener(this);
            //    classSchedule.setOnClickListener(this);
            //    profile.setOnClickListener(this);
            //   fee.setOnClickListener(this);
            //   progressReport.setOnClickListener(this);

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            navigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new Dashboard())
                    .commit();


            if (id == R.id.dashboard_layout) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard())
                        .commit();
            } else if (id == R.id.view_fee) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new Fee())
                        .commit();

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }


    }
```

my dashboard fragment

```
public class Dashboard extends Fragment {


        public Dashboard() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        }


    }
```

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: Remove your add dashboard fragment and try

Comment: Its not helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use text view clicks instead of taking menuItems you have not added any menu item in menu.xml it will not really work you need to try like this,

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    LinearLayout calendar, classSchedule, progressReport, profile, fee;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        calendar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.calender_layout);
        classSchedule = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.class_schedule);
        profile = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_profile);
        fee = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_fee);
        progressReport = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_report);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.accept, R.string.appbar_scrolling_view_behavior);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cal);
        textView1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();

        if (id == R.id.cal) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard())
                    .commit();

        }

    }

}
```

you need to set id for all textview you want to click on

```
                      <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:id="@+id/cal"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Comment: Thank you .It really helps very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using menu item for that you need to define directly textview or Layour whatever you defined in your menu drawer and open click on that particular item like following way .

Here is the your one of the linear layout id is view_fee.
Handle click event of that perticular view and open the fragment

```
 LinearLayout lineFree = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_fee);
        lineFree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new Dashboard())
                        .commit();


                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
```

Comment: No need put anything because now you are handle all event on particular view OnClick().

Comment: Welcome Dear,      .